# XML parsing issue with '&' in element text continued

Tags: java, xml, parsing

For the issue discussed in 
[XML parsing issue with '&' in element text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838316/xml-parsing-issue-with-in-element-text)
I had the same problem, but replacing `&` with `&amp;` before processing does not fix the problem

Here's my code:

```
convertedString = convertedString.replaceAll("& ", "&amp;");
convertedString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(convertedString);
```

Here's my error:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:253: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:249)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:124)
```

...

Appreciated if anyone can help, many thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be escaping the `&`?  Why are you trying to replace it??  Isn't this basically the same problem you're having from the previous question??

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML parsing issue with '&' in element text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838316/xml-parsing-issue-with-in-element-text)

Comment: hi guys, I've updated my questions above, sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
convertedString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(convertedString);
convertedString = convertedString.replaceAll("& ", "&amp; "); // Also note the added space
```

[`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) would actually convert `&amp;` back to `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Arjan, and sorry guys, this is probably a wrong question asked. I just realised that it's the DocumentBuilder parser that's complaining, where it does not accept xml containing ampersand such as: `"<text> Health & Safety </text>"`, However having ampersand inside xml content was a requirement from my client, unless there's other way to get around DOMparsers on this, I'll have to manipulate the front end, i.e. jsp's to display `&` instead of `&amp;`

Comment: All html clients display the string `&amp;` as `&`, so you should not need to manipulate anything for that. If you allow user input, you'll have to fix that before you save it.