# Parsing Yahoo finance data

Tags: google-apps-script, yahoo-finance

First things first... I really tried to educate myself about the syntax for google app script and in particle Regex, but somehow I don't get it.

I am trying to retrieve data from yahoo finance for a particular stock and then parse information like earnings date for my spreadsheet.

I can retrieve the data and see the values in the debugger, but I am not able to extract the data. For instance, the earnings data for Bristol-Myers on Feb 02, 2024.

Here is the code snipped:

```
const url = `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BMY?p=BMY&.tsrc=fin-srch`;
 const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
 const contentText = res.getContentText();


  //var body_start = contentText.indexOf('<div id="Main"');
  var body_start = contentText.indexOf('<td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Earnings Date</span></td>');
  var body_end = contentText.lastIndexOf("</span></td>");
  var body_data = contentText.slice(body_start, body_end);
 console.log(body_data); 
 //const date = contentText.match(/<td(?:.*?)data-test="MARKET_CAP-value">(\d{3}.\d{3} [A-Z]{1});
```

and I tried to get at least the first three letter... so "Feb" with this code section:

```
var date = body_data.match(/<td(?:.*?)data-test="EARNINGS_DATE-value"><span>([A-Za-z]{3})<\/td>/);
```

How can I change the code above to get the full date saved in variable "date"?

Thank you very much in advance!

I have tried to isolate the problem and I tried to get the full date step-by-step, without success.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use XmlService to parse the page but it contains too much junk that can't be parsed.  See this article [XML parsing issue with '&' in element text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838316/xml-parsing-issue-with-in-element-text)

So i decided to look at the small section of html that you extracted and noticed that the date was contained in the following row/cell.

```
<td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="EARNINGS_DATE-value">
  <span>Feb 02, 2024</span>
</td>
```

From there I wrote a small function to get the date.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BMY?p=BMY&.tsrc=fin-srch";
    let res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
    let text = res.getContentText();
    let start = text.indexOf("EARNINGS_DATE-value");
    if( start < 0 ) throw " Date not found";
    // get date
    start = text.indexOf("<span>",start);
    if( start < 0 ) throw " Date not found";
    let end = text.indexOf("</span>",start);
    let date = text.substring(start+6,end);
    console.log(date);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err)
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
10:09:36 AM Notice  Execution started
10:09:38 AM Info    Feb 02, 2024
10:09:37 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

**References**

- [String.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)
- [String.substring()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)