# In my xml file comes a tip in eclipse ide

Tags: java, xml, spring

```
<bean id="cacheRedisConnectionFactory"  class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
    destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="database" value="1" />
    <property name="password" value="ms25J23#RA1~*3&c" />
</bean>
```

In this line : `<property name="password" value="ms25J23#RA1~*3&c" />`

Eclipse is telling me : The reference to entity "c" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944392/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-the-reference-to-entity-t-must-end-with-the

Comment: Replace the last part `3&c`with `3&amp;c`. The character `&` has a special meaning in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is simply invalid. There are only 5 special characters in XML: `"`, `'`, `&`, `<` and `>`. If you use these characters inside a text content of your XML doc you can escape them as entity (`&` => `&amp;`; amp like ampersand).

PS: Please, remove the `spring`-tag.

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand `&` is a special character in XML. So, if you want to have an ampersand as value in XML, you need to escape it.

Ampersand in XML is an entity reference with the following format:

```
&#nnn;
&#hhh;
&name;
```

As you can see, the format is closed with a `;`.

So, in order to have `&` as a value, escape it to `&amp;`. This is recognised by XML engine as `&`. So, here is the valid XML element.

```
<property name="password" value="ms25J23#RA1~*3&amp;c" />
```

Reference: [List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)