# How to retrieve link from email message using the Gmail plugin/GMail API for Java/Jakarta Mail API/...?

Tags: email, groovy, jakarta-mail, gmail-api, katalon-studio

I am using Katalon Studio, and need to retrieve some sign-up link from test email inbox. I found some API/service to access the test email inbox, can get the message I need from it, and it's a string of what looks like HTML.

I don't care about the HTML, I just want to "click on" the link in that email message!

How do I do that!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you successfully have the message string, [here's how you can **retrieve** the link from it](https://gist.github.com/MikeWarren2014/65232ccc5d7357153c814398cb486990), assuming that your email message retrival method call returns HTML string.

To save you some clicking:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory

import org.w3c.dom.Element

// feel free to make this your own :)
public final class EmailUtils {
/**
     * **NOTE**: forked from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2269464/2027839 , and then refactored
     * 
     * Processes HTML, using XPath
     * 
     * @param html
     * @param xpath
     * @return the result 
     */
    public static String ProcessHTML(String html, String xpath) {

        final String properHTML = this.ToProperHTML(html);

        final Element document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream( properHTML.bytes ))
                .documentElement;
        return XPathFactory.newInstance()
                .newXPath()
                .evaluate( xpath, document );
    }

    private static String ToProperHTML(String html) {
        // SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125599/2027839
        String properHTML = html.replaceAll( "(&(?!amp;))", "&amp;" );

        if (properHTML.contains('<!DOCTYPE html'))
            return properHTML;


        return """<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        ${properHTML}
    </body>
</html>
""";
    }
}
```

From there, you'll have to log out your HTML message string (or put debug breakpoint around your method call and extract it from debugger), [pretty print it](https://jsonformatter.org/html-pretty-print), and from there, you can use your web-testing skills to create some xpath selector string for the actual link.

Then, you use my code like:

```
WebUI.navigateToUrl(yourEmailMessageContent, "${yourLinkXPath}/@href");
```

To be fair, email messages can take some time to hit inboxes. Hence you might also want to have some retry logic in place. Here is example from my real project code base:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
// ...rest of imports

public final class EmailUtils { 

    //...rest of code base

    public static String ExtractSignUpLink() {
        String link;

        int retryAttempts;

        ActionHandler.Handle({
            link = this.ProcessHTML(this.GetLatestMessageBody(30),
                    "//a[.//div[@class = 'sign-mail-btn-text']]/@href");
        }, { boolean success, ex ->
            if (success)
                return;
            // handle ex
            if (((GoogleJsonResponseException)ex).getDetails().getCode() >= 400)
                throw ex;
            sleep(1000 * 2**retryAttempts++);
        }, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(15))

        return link;
    }

    //...rest of code base
}

public final class ActionHandler {
    public static void Handle(Closure onAction, Closure onDone, long timeOut) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeSeconds();
        while (System.currentTimeSeconds() < startTime + timeOut) {
            try {
                onDone(true, onAction());
                return;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                onDone(false, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```